# sql code doesn't work in method install (prestashop module)

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I want to have a table for my module and a foreign key with the ps_customer (customer_id) table, but the sql code I put doesn't work and doesn't give an error.

`public function install()
{

```
    Db::getInstance()->execute("
        ALTER TABLE `ps_customer`
        ADD id_wallet INT NOT NULL AFTER `id_customer`;

        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'wallet` (
            `i`d INT NOT NULL,
            `id_customer` INT NOT NULL,
            `cash` INT DEFAULT 0,
            `data_add` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            `data_upd` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
            FOREIGN KEY (`id_customer`) REFERENCES `ps_customer`(`id_wallet`) 
        )
    ");
    
    return (parent::install()
        && $this->registerHook('displayNav1')
            );
}`
```

I followed this link [create-table](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/505584-create-table-in-db/)

Comment: You have two SQL statements in there, and a few typos.  I suggest you first split the statements into two separate `execute()` calls, and take care with your quotes

Comment: (Looks like you have an extra quote before `CREATE`, and also `\`i\`d` is not a valid column name.  Did you mean `\`id\``?)

Comment: Also your table name is not valid, because your `_DB_PREFIX_` substitution is inside single quotes, but the whole string is inside double quotes...

Comment: Also your table name is not valid, because your `_DB_PREFIX_` substitution is inside single quotes, but the whole string is inside double quotes...

Comment: Your `install` method doesn't return an error because you don't use the return of the `execute()` method. In addition of what @RobEyre said, you should consider using its result in your return statement. :)
(it won't give you a detailed error but at list will tell you something went wrong.)